# Is glCompileShader optional?

Tags: opengl, shader

While debugging my system, I found out that all the shaders I used were never compiled. All the GLSL Programs were happily linked and working like a charm.

I have searched the entire code base for calls to `glCompileShader`, but none were found.

My question then is: Is this a specific behaviour of the implementation I am working with? Is shader compilation carried out implicitly when linking a program? Is it optional? If that is the case, what advantages are there in doing it explicitly, apart from retrieving the error log?

I could not find any case such as mine in the documentation, if I missed something can you please point me to it?

My vendor is NVIDIA (driver 337.88)

**EDIT:** Also, I am *NOT* using `glCreateShaderProgram()`, but simply `glCreateProgram()` for the creation of shader programs.

Comment: It is not supposed to work that way, but there is one way that comes to my mind immediately that would allow you to bypass compiling shader objects. Newer versions of GL allow you to load pre-linked Program Binaries; I sincerely doubt this is what is going on in your code base, since that does not negate the need to compile/link programs at least once initially and then again whenever the driver/hardware changes. It is basically useful for caching linked programs to reduce load time on future executions and you would definitely know if your software were designed to work that way.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, I knew this was wrong and I was surprise about that in first place as well. To double check I've removed all the glCompileShader call via the refactoring option of VS (to not risk to miss something), still the same behaviour. And indeed I'm not using pre-linked programs

Comment: Is it possible that you use some kind of toolkit that builds shaders for you, so that you don't see the shader compilation if you just look at your own code? It definitely shouldn't happen magically all by itself. The specs list as one reason for `glLinkProgram()` to fail: "One or more of the shader objects attached to program are not compiled
successfully."

Comment: @RetoKoradi if there's nothing like that built in with Visual Studio that intercept my code or GLEW does this somehow (can't see how, but I don't know what to believe), then no. I've also tried to delete glCompileShader from previous, much simpler, applications. Same result.

Comment: For example, even with a random tutorial from: opengl-tutorial.org (just picked first random code I didn't wrote that I had lying around) exhibit same behaviour if I remove all glCompileShader calls.

Comment: I can actually confirm this behavior with nVidia 331.17 on Linux. It seems like it compiles any not yet compiled shader objects at link time. This looks like just another nvidiaism to me, you shouldn't rely on that, though.

Comment: @derhass Glad I'm not a visionary then :) Yes I would never rely on that, I corrected it straight away, but the issue puzzled me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was mostly resolved in the comments (thanks to @Andon, @derhass, and others), but since it's an interesting question, let me summarize it in an answer, and add some more data.

Not taking pre-compiled shaders into consideration, you need to compile your shaders by calling `glCompileShader()` before linking the program with `glLinkProgram()`. Based on the data I collected, skipping the `glCompileShader()` call works fine on:

- NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M under Windows 8.1.
- NVIDIA under Linux (from @derhass).
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 620M under Windows 8 (from @cifz)

It fails on:

- Intel HD 4600 under Windows 8.1.
- Intel Iris under Mac OS 10.9.2.
- iPad Air under iOS 7.1.
- Two different Android tablets.

So this behavior seems clearly isolated to NVIDIA. The specs say that compiling the shaders before linking is necessary. From the 3.3 specs:

> Linking will also fail if one or more of the shader objects, attached to program are not compiled successfully.

The 4.4 specs are a little less clear, turning the possible error conditions into a list that starts with:

> Linking can fail ...

Normally **can** suggests that behavior is optional, but I'm not sure that this is the intention here. It looks to me like the specs were just reformatted, and the intended behavior has not changed. So IMHO, this is a bug. Not a very severe one, because all legal usage still works, but I don't think what NVIDIA is doing strictly follows the specs.

In any case, calling `glCompileShader()` before `glLinkProgram()` is necessary for your code to work across platforms.

Comment: I'd call it an "undocumented extension", because all valid programs works, but otherwise invalid programs also works.

Comment: On the subject of wishy-washy language, *"One or more of the shader objects attached to `program` are not compiled successfully"* leaves room for the implementation to compile at link-time without actually violating anything. Perhaps this is the stance NV took? It does not actually say *"one or more of the shader objects attached to `program` weren't compiled beforehand"*. That would be inline with NV's [previously documented statement](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/glsl/glsl_release_notes.pdf) that `glCompileShader (...)` only parses and validates syntax in their implementation.

Comment: I would be curious to see what the state of the shader object's `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` is after NVIDIA implicitly compiles the shader though.